# lambda expression is not working in .net mvc

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, lambda

I have three tables many to many relationship I have joined the three tables and select the value I want but now I need to select one row from the query result by specifying the id this is my three

[image: databse er diagram]
And this is the query using LINQ lambda expression :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Getdata(string batchcode)
    {
        //var studentid = (from a in db.Studentassignbatches
        //                 where a.batch_code == batchcode
        //                 select new { a.UserId });

        //var id = db.UserDetails.Where(a => a.UserId.Equals(db.Studentassignbatches.Where(x => x.batch_code.Equals(batchcode)).Select(x => x.UserId))).Select(a => a.id);

        var id = db.UserDetails
            .Join(db.Studentassignbatches,
            x => x.UserId, y => y.UserId,
            (x, y) => new { x, y })
            .Where(c => c.y.batch_code == batchcode)
            .Select(d => new UserDetail
            {
                id = d.x.id
            });
        return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

the result will be like that using sql query

sql query

```
select UserDetails.id 
from UserDetails 
inner join 
Studentassignbatches on
Studentassignbatches.UserId=UserDetails.UserId  
where
Studentassignbatches.batch_code = 'CCNA Security-1';
```

and result will be something like=>
[image]

if multiple then will show multiple result.

I am not understanding what wrong I have done.
or just i am not getting my result because of using lambda expression ? not using linq???
help please?

Comment: Are using Entity?

Comment: Your model makes no sense. A user has one password but multiple details, like first name? I think the Users and UserDetails table should be merged.

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish. What is the result you are looking for? The linq is very complex for something simple, but none of it makes sense: `db.Studentassignbatches.Where(s => s.batch_code == 'CCNA Security-1').Select(s => s.UserId)` has the same result. No need to link other tables. So please update your question.

Comment: what is DB ? a DbContext ?

Answer (score 2):

This feels over-complicated why join when this is done for you by the ORM ...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Getdata(string batchcode)
    {
        var detailIds = db.UserDetails
            .Where(d => d.User.Studentassignbatches.Any(b => b.batch_code == batchcode))
            .Select(d => d.id)
            .ToList();
        return Json(detailIds, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

Also, as stated previously, this model makes no sense.